# In a replication setup, does corrupted data also gets replicated?

Tags: mysql, replication, high-availability, corruption

Say one of the tables got corrupted, will that corrupted table still get replicated to the other DB? Or, will the replication stop to prevent the other DB from being corrupted too?

Note: Question is for both master-master or master-slave setup.

Comment: Elaborate on what you mean by "corrupted data".  Also, provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';`  And version of MySQL.

Comment: @RickJames This is only theoretical question. I'm not experiencing it right now but I've experienced a "corrupted" table before in MyISAM and was able to "repair" it via phpmyadmin only but that was not a replicated table. FWIW I'll be using InnoDB and MySQL 5.7 on the theoretical replicated db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crash often leaves MyISAM tables in need of "REPAIR".  Switch to InnoDB to avoid such.

Even then, it was rarely the "data" that was corrupted, just the index file (`.MYI`).  The index is maintained separately on each server; replication is not involved.

Bottom line: *Don't use MyISAM any more*.

If the Master discovers corruption, it will halt.  In this case, nothing will go to the Slave.

Replication involves sending changes (either in the form of write SQL statements or the effect of those statements), so corruption is not propagated.

If your definition of "corruption" includes a malicious `DROP TABLE`, that "corruption" *will* be propagated to the Slave.

Comment: Is that simply because MyISAM isn't ACID compliant? I note most of the tables in the master-master setup I inherited are MyISAM. I assumed there was a reason for that so I have left them be. Your answer suggests that is a mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but sorry this doesn't quite answer the main question though: Assuming InnoDB is used and table corruption still happened, will the replication activity halt to prevent the destination DB from being corrupted too?

Comment: @IMB - I added some more.

Comment: @topshot - ACID is the sole reason.  However, in implementing ACID, the data format is made much more robust.  And much more complicated.  One person implemented MyISAM.  Later another person implemented InnoDB.  There was probably no common code until the two products merged as separate "Engines" in version 4.1.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had read in the past that switching engines was just an `alter table` but will research more and test on Dev before moving forward. One thing I do like about MyISAM is you can quickly tell what databases exist and move them easily within the OS file system.

Comment: @topshot - True, InnoDB tables must not be manipulated in the filesystem.  [_Here_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) is my collection of things to consider when converting from MyISAM to InnoDB.